# Need help adding name to qrcode so i can save to parse

Tags: parse-platform, swift2

I cannot figure out why im getting this error.
This is the function to update a guest(Participant). I'm trying to save the Qr code i created to a PFFile and save to parse.

```
func update() {
   _ = LabelText

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Participant")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(LabelText) {
        (Update: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    Update!["firstname"] = self.firstnameTF!.text
    Update!["lastname"] = self.lastnameTF!.text
    Update!["grade"] = self.gradeTF!.text
    Update!["teacher"] = self.teacherTF.text
    Update!["email"] = self.emailTF.text
    Update!["phone"] = self.phoneTF.text
    Update!["transportation"] = self.transportationTF.text

    Update!.saveInBackground()
    print("updated")
        if self.QrImage == nil {
            print("Image is Blank")
            return
        }else{
            //Image is not blank

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.QrImage!, 1)
        let parseImageFile = PFFile(data: imageData!)
        Update!.setObject(parseImageFile!, forKey: "qrcode")

        Update!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock( {
            (success: Bool , error: NSError?) -> Void in
        })
        }
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});

    }
}
```

I can see the image in the self.QrImage field and i only get the error on:
    let parseImageFile = PFFile(data: imageData!)

Why am i getting a nil error when it should have a value there?

Edit 1:

```
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.QrImage!)
        let parseImageFile = PFFile(data: imageData!)
        Update!.setObject(parseImageFile!, forKey: "qrcode")

        Update!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock( {
            (success: Bool , error: NSError?) -> Void in
        })
        }
```

Same result."fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Edit 2:

So it seems there must be a name value associated with the image before you upload it to parse. My Image is of a Qrcode i create from other data. here's my code:

```
    func displayQrCode() {
    print(self.qrdata.text)
    let data =      self.qrdata.text!.dataUsingEncoding(NSISOLatin1StringEncoding)

    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")

    filter!.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
    filter!.setValue("Q", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")
    self.qrcodeImage = filter!.outputImage!

    let scaleX = qrCode.frame.size.width / qrcodeImage!.extent.size.width
    let scaleY = qrCode.frame.size.height / qrcodeImage!.extent.size.height

    let transformedImage = qrcodeImage!.imageByApplyingTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleX, scaleY))

    self.qrCode.image = UIImage(CIImage: transformedImage)

    print("QRCode Made")
}
```

now i guess i need to add a name to the self.qrCode.image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what needs to be done before you use UIImagePNGRepresentation:

```
self.QrImage = UIImage(named: "qrcode.png")
```